# remove every before and after a substring

Tags: jquery, regex

I think I need regex, but my regex noobtown.

given this string:

```
/MyUrl?query=http://www.domain.com/category/index.jsp%3FcategoryId&bonkers=Upp&this=that
```

how can I simply just get the domain out of this: So remove the preceeding

```
/MyURL?query=
```

and then everything from and including &bonkers and onward. Basically just need the straight url with no parameters so the result looks like

```
http://www.domain.com/category/index.jsp%3FcategoryId%3D4414047
```

Knowing absolutely nothing about regex I got this far

```
.*url\?q=(.*)&sa
```

but that doesn't quite do it. I'm attempting to parse a string in jquery to just return each URL in a matched select

```
$(data).find(".link a").each(function(){
                    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
                    //returns string with garbage before and after
                  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Could you supply a couple sample input and outputs please? I don't seem to be totally following where the matched string should end. Maybe post a link where your regex fails and include the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Hi something like this would work. You declare the parameters you want to get out of your query string i.e. `Query` and then do a regex to only bring back your full query string with that parameter.. then a alert will tell you what it is.

```
  function getQueryStringValue() {
        var Query = "query";
        Query = Query.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + Query + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        var QueryString = results === null ? "" :
decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        alert(QueryString);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe explain the regex to the OP so he actually learns something?

Comment: This is pretty much the [first answer of the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript#answer-901144).